# what is the difference between the time format mi and mm?

Tags: mysql, datetime-format, time-format

When I google for tutorials about date/time format, I have noticed that the minute has two different format. Some times it mi and some times it is mm. e.g: HH:mm:ss and HH:mi:ss.

Question: what is the difference between mi and mm and when to use these different formats?

Answer (score 0):

Some systems opted for MM (month) and MI (minute) as there is better distinction than MM (month) and mm (miniute) and isn't prone to errors introduced by case-sensitivity/conversions.

Behind the scenes, the values will most likely be enumerators, so when case is preserved, no difference will be seen.